# How do I add a Domain Services class to a Silverlight app or RIA Services library?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, domainservices

I have tried several guides I find online, and nothing seems to work. I am trying to follow this guide, Setting up a new Silverlight 4 Project with WCF RIA Services, but when I try and add a Domain Services class to the RIA x.Web project, I get an error about an index dialoguie out of range etc. Google reveals this is maybe because VS can't find a connection string, although I have added one in App.config.

Then, if I try and add the DS class directly into my Silverlight host, bypassing teh RIA project, I get the same error, until I add an App.Config. After that, I can proceed an iota further, and I get to choose my DbContext and select a few entity classes to include in the DS class. But then I get an unspecified error.

Maybe something code-first specific? I find a NuGet package for CodeFirst EF and RIA,  RIAServices.EntityFramework, but it doesn't support EF 4.3. I am going to try and duplicate my model in a dirty old edmx model and see.

Has anyone had any success doing any of this in VS 2012?

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding connection strings to the Web.Config not an App.config

Comment: The designer apparently looks in App.config, as the class library doesn't have a web.config.

Comment: You also should copy the system.web etc entries from the app.config into your web project web.config (the one with the <your-project-name>.aspx & .html files). This allows request to be routed to the domain service libraries.